# Can I write a LinkedIn recommendation for a mentor?

Tags: linkedin, recommendation-letter

An expert in a field I'm interested gave a few fascinating lectures and I ended up talking to him about my project and we discussed my approach. Despite the fact that we weren't working together on a regular basis, I thought of writing a recommendation for him to thank him for help as I consider him somewhat of a mentor.
But on LinkedIn there's no such option available when specifying my relationship to this person so I thought it might not be appropriate to write a recommendation for a mentor.

**Is it ethical to write a LinkedIn recommendation for someone who was mentoring you during a relatively short period of time?**

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well, OK, but he main question was if it was ethical, not how do I post stuff on Linkedin

Comment: Welcome to the site Alexander. I've edited your question significantly. Could you clarify if you talked to this person only one time or if you actually established a mentor relationship which requires multiple meetings/discussions? If it's the former, regardless of the answer to this question I'd say that this person wasn't a mentor.

Comment: @Lilienthal, first of all, thanks for editing, I'm quite common with the SO rules, but here I thought I should really make an emphasis on the fact that I was impressed by the stuff he said. And I don't think it was just a one-time talk.

Comment: @Lilienthal Considering your second comment, 1) he definitely does quite a lot of public speaking 2) I thanked him in person 3) I don't have a blog :)

Comment: I think 'is it appropriate...' might be a better question. Does your mentor want you to write one? maybe ask him first, rather than doing it unsolicited.

Comment: @AlexanderM. I've preserved the essence of your explanation, but we generally prefer questions that aren't too specific to a particular situation. Consider editing it again if you want to include extra information or felt that I removed too much. As for the blog thing: this is one of the few situations where writing a LinkedIn article might be useful/appropriate, as long as your review also includes some useful information for your network. Since your network might not be that large, a school blog review or such could also work. But really, just thank him by mail, he'll appreciate it.

Comment: I'm my case I wrote a recommendation for someone who I was constantly in touch during my whole career, he was first my degree adviser, then a professor, then my senior design adviser, he accepted my recommendation and replied to me saying how honored he felt for that, and that he wanted to keep in touch with me and that I could contact him whenever I needed/wanted to. So yes it is ethically appropriate to give credit where credit is due under reason I put (reported to subjectA in the university of...)

Comment: @AlexanderM.: Don't worry about your question being closed. You're going to have plenty of reopen votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely ethical, and it's a wise move on your part for two reasons:

1. It's a great way to nominally repay your mentor for the help and advice he/she gave to you.
2. It's a great way to recapture your mentor's attention as you begin your career. You may need his/her recommendation when you get a job offer in the near future or even in the distant future. If LinkedIn remains a going concern, then he/she will likely remember that you wrote a nice recommendation for him/her on LinkedIn.

Comment: Mentoring is an important skill, I would put a lot of value in a recommendation from a mentoree